# Send email to list of recipients python smtp

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp

I am having trouble sending an email to a list of recipients using an smtp.

I can send the email to the first recipient but not the rest. My recipients are in a list. I have tried turning the list into a string. As well as adding a comma or a semicolon to each email in the list but each to no avail.

My email list is formatted like this:

```
['name@email.com', 'name@email.com']
```

And I am using this to send it:

```
from Dmail import Email
sender_email = 'sender@email.com'

with Email(mail_server="smtp.myserver.org", sender_email=sender_email, mail_port=25, mail_use_ssl=False,
       mail_use_tls=False) as email:
email.send("Test Body", email_list, subject="test")
```

Any help on this appreciated.
Currently, I have the email sending to myself and I can see that there are multiple recipients in the "to" column, but none of them are actually receiving the email.
Using Python 3.9+
Thank you.

Comment: since you should be using Bcc anyhow, just look at how this particular email library accepts entries for Bcc.  What is `Dmail`?

Comment: Yeah. I'm also having a hard time finding out what Dmail is or what it's API is.  Without knowing what sort of args `email.send` expects, it's really hard to answer this question.

Comment: [link](https://pypi.org/project/Dmail)
It's interesting, when I use a CC it picks up on the first email still. I'm just going to abort using Dmail at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by doing:

```
email_list= '; '.join(email_list)
```

and

```
email.send("Test Body", email_list.split(';'), subject="test")
```